# How to receive BroadcastReceiver.onReceive() in a seperate thread?

Tags: android, android-intent

I wonder whether I can handle `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` inside a separate thread. The current code looks like this:

```
public class myService extends Service { 
    ...
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBluetoothPairingStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
    {  ...
        which thread context is this run in?   
        ...   
    }
    public void setup()
    {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
        this.registerReceiver(mBluetoothPairingStateReceiver, filter);
    }
    ...
    public void onCreate() {
         setup();
    }
}
```

I guess the service has a dedicated thread that handles the event queue ?

Is it possible to create a thread and register registerReceiver() to that thread?
Do I need to call into some event handling loop to be able to receive events 
in that thread?

Comment: Yep, you can do that. And if you use a `HandlerThread`, it'll have a `Looper` ready for you. There are examples in the linked duplicates.